# search followers with a specific property

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to fill a text field with a list of followers from a specific city. I thought the javascript search syntax should be :

```
var myText = document.getElementById('target');
SC.get('/users/MY_USER/followers',{city:'Berlin'},function(followers) {
  for (i=0; i < followers.length; i++){
     myText.innerHTML += followers[i].username + ' </br> ';
  }
});
```

The request returns the whole list of `MY_USER`'s followers instead of getting only the ones from Berlin. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the backend. Are you sure you are filtering the content corectly on the server?

Edit:

Ups, I've missed the soundcloud tag....
According to [this](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) you can use only the *q* parameter.
Instead you can filter the results yourself:

```
var myText = document.getElementById('target');
SC.get('/users/MY_USER/followers', function(followers) {
   for (i = 0; i < followers.length; i++){
      if(followers[i].city == 'Berlin') {
          myText.innerHTML += followers[i].username + ' </br> ';
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Since the server belongs to soundcloud, I sure hope it's returning the filtered content...

Comment: that's the point of my question, I want to be sure this is the correct request to filter the content.

Comment: Yeah... Didn't see the soundcloud tag. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yep, this works but is kind of brutal since it forces the client to download all followers before filtering. If someone knows a better server-side filtering method, I'd be happy to get a pointer.

Comment: Currently there is no way to filter the followers by city. The best thing to do is to filter them in your application logic. Someday it might get added to the API but for now its not.